# iOS Simulator installed apps location in Xcode 4.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode

Where can I find the apps installed on the iOS Simulator?

I am running Xcode 4.3.1. I have found the location of the simulator at

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app

but for the life of me I can't find the installed apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my computer, it's `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications`

Simple `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]);` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and then realized that my whole iPhone Simulator directory was now under my User folder:

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/[app guid]
```

The one trick with that was that the Library folder was a hidden folder, which I was able to see after turning hidden folders on in system prefs.

Comment: To make the user `Library` folder visible again: `chflags nohidden ~/Library`